# Instant soreness vs onset soreness

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, bodyweight

Hardly happening with upper body, more so with lower body.

When I have some serious leg training I can barely walk for the rest of the day and the -muscular ache- starts during the workout.

Which is different from what I get sometimes, more often with my upper body but happens to legs too...but rarely. No -muscular ache-  during the working day but incredible soreness the day after and the day after that.

Comment: Pain or soreness? They're two different things. Pain is generally a short, sharp, stabbing thing where you generally have to stop what you're doing (dislocating a limb or pulling a muscle). Soreness is an ache in your muscles (sometimes joints). Or do you mean discomfort, muscle burn during a set (muscular pump) where it feels like you can't carry on with an exercise and stairs scare the hell out of you?

Comment: So. What is the question?